# mitmproxy change proxy localhost addres

Tags: proxy, localhost, mitmproxy

I have an external proxy server with authentication.
To use google chrome with proxy without authentication I use `mitmproxy --mode upstream`.
Everything works fine.
But, websites detect my IP as localhost - `Remote Address: [::1]:8080`
Is there any way I can fix this? That websites detect my IP like IP external proxy server?
Thanks!